# Extracting values from sql query like string

Tags: java, string

I wanted to extract test 1 and  this.test2  I did below and later processed the right hand side

```
 string1:test1 = {{this.test2}}

 String[] parts = string1.split("=");
```

I'm planning to extract/print  id1 and id2, product_application,product1,this.product2 from above String.How can I split the string and extract them :

**Test1:**

```
id1 IN (SELECT id2 FROM product_application WHERE product1 = {{this.product2}})
```

**Test2:**

```
id3 IN (SELECT id4 FROM location WHERE region1 = {{this.region2}}
```

I want to extract or print  like below.

**Output for string 1:**

```
id1, id2, product_application, product1, product2
```

**Output for string 2:**

```
id3, id4, location, region1, region2
```

Comment: Its more of url parsing I am trying to parse sql like string

Comment: Sorry your question is confusing to me.  What string(s) do you have and what results do you want to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/Sh1bjZ/1) you can use it :

```
String str = 
       "id1 IN (SELECT id2 FROM product_application WHERE product1 = {{this.product2}})";

String regex = "(id\\d+)|(product_\\w+)|(product\\d+)";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(str);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
while (mat.find()) {
    list.add(mat.group());
}
System.out.println(list);
```

**Output**

```
[id1, id2, product_application, product1, product2]
```

---

**EDIT**

Your string is a little compecated, so i don't know if that help you or not, it work fine with the two examples in your question :

```
String[] spl = str.replaceAll("IN|SELECT|FROM|WHERE|(this\\.)|[(){}=,]|(\\s{2,})", " ").
        replaceAll("\\s+", " ").split("\\s");
```

**The idea is :**

1. replace every thing `IN or SELECT or FROM or WHERE or this. or [(){}=,]` with a space.
2. replace multiple Strings with one space
   3.split the result with space, and you will get only your result.

Comment: Thanks  but  id1, id2, product_application, product1, product2  are variable I can get  a different string it can be id3,id4,product_application_region,product3,product4

Comment: mmm, you had to make this in the first time @javascriptlearner ok i will check what i can do

Comment: its ok @javascriptlearner the name of `idxxx` are all like this format, or you can find for example a diffirent name?

Comment: @javascriptlearner can you please answer my question i'm trying to help you here :)

Comment: Thanks. It  can be anything  does not follow idxxx format.It can be like " test1 IN (SELECT test2...

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot.